# How to find the total number of drinks possible

Tags: combinatorics

If I sold coffee in 4 sizes (small, medium, large, and extra large) and 4 varieties (Kenyan, Sumatran, Kona, and Columbian). Customers can choose to add one or more syrups that come in 5 flavors (chocolate, vanilla, hazelnut, raspberry, and coconut). How many different coffee drinks can be made?
I thought this was formula nCr but I have try it so many way and never get the right answer.

Comment: I tried the 4x4x5=80 and the answer was wrong the correct answer was 512.  Do not know how to work this problem.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine the combination of hazelnut, raspberry, and coconut in the same coffee ... it doesn't seem like a pleasant choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you have $4 \times 4= 16$ drinks without syrups.

Now when you have to choose your syrups, for each of the five syrups you can either say yes or no, which means $2^5=32$ different syrup possibilities.

So you have $16 \times 32=512$ different drinks.

Comment: Why not? The question says *"one or more syrups"*.

Comment: I am sorry but I still do not understand how you got 32 possibilities on syrup.

Comment: When you are about to choose your syrups you can say either yes or no to each one. So there are two options when you want to choose chocolate, and then two options for vanilla and so on. So $2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2= 32$ Another way you can think of it is this: When you are going to choose the syrup, you can choose 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 syrups. If you choose one syrup then you have $\binom{5}{1}$ options. If you choose two syrups, you have $\binom{5}{2}$ options and so on. You add all these: $\binom{5}{1} + \binom{5}{2} + \binom{5}{3}+ \binom{5}{4} + \binom{5}{5} = 32$. Same answer :)

Answer (score 0):

$4 \text{ (sizes)} \times 4 \text{ (varieties)} \times 2^5 \text{ (with or without each syrup)} = 512$

Answer (score 0):

Four sizes times four blends = 16 choices before syrups.

There is one way to choose without syrups. Multiply this by the 16 combos found above.

There are 5 ways to choose one syrup. Multiply this by the 16 combos above.

There are 5 times 4 ways to pick 2 syrups. Multiply this by the 16 combos again.

Repeat. Add together. The pattern should be clear.